# Using selenium, how to select a the text in a paragraph which is nested in a div element?

Tags: selenium

Sample code:

```
<div class="loginbox">some code</div>
<div class="loginbox">other code</div>
<div class="loginbox">
    <p> style="color: Red;">Test Extract</p>     
</div>
```

Using Selenium Web Driver, I would like to extract the text `Test Extract` within the paragraph element which is nested within a div, whose class name is shared with other div classes. c# preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below method:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='loginbox']/p")).getText();
```

**EDITED**
You should use `=` inside the square braces like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='loginbox']/p");
```

Comment: Thank you Harish!


    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='loginbox']/p")).Text;

Comment: Sorry! I missed the .getText() part. Edited the answer. You can accept the answer if it worked.. Thanks.

Comment: @Annie why are using xpath if you can simply find it by using cssSelector, I would suggest you always  use cssSelector if it could be possible because it's much faster than xpath...:)

Answer (score 0):

C# code to get the text from the locator specified,

```
IWebElement element = Browser.GetElementByCssSelector("div.loginbox p");
string text = element.Text;
```